# How to prevent some variables from showing up in python Class object?

Tags: python

I have a class that contains some variables for users, inside the shell i want to fetch the first user from the database, i am using `__dict__` attribute to see all the user data, there is some data that i don't want them to show up inside the dictionary like his password and credentials, here is my **code** :

```
class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String())
    password = db.Column(db.String())
    public_id = db.Column(db.String(), default=uuid.uuid4)
    my_code = db.Column(db.String())
    credential = db.Column(db.String())

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.username)

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, value):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, value)

    def check_code(self, code):
        return True if code == self.my_code else False

    @property
    def get_id(self):
        return "{id}".format(id=self.public_id)
```

How to prevent **password** and **credential** from showing up inside the dictionary if i used `__dict__` attribute ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to filter `User.__dict__` getting from it only the data you want to show. There is no way a class attribute to be out of `Class.__dict__`, this is the way Python map all the attributes.

Comment: Ohhh i see, so there is no why that the class will return just the data the i will specify not all the attributes. Thanks dude at least for your interest ;)